# sql query where like clause adding extra space in value

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching a keyword in DB that is `Bootjack Fire and Rescue Foundation`
As there is single space after a word, my query is `

```
WHERE `title` LIKE  '%Bootjack Fire and  Rescue Foundation%'
```

Why are there two space after the `and` keyword in the search title as you can see in the query?

**add query**

```
$keyword = 'Bootjack Fire and Rescue Foundation';

$this->db->select('stores.id,store_title,store_category_id,store_sub_category_id,store_sub_category_type_id,sub_category_fourth,store_link');
$this->db->from('stores');
$this->db->join('users','users.id=stores.user_id');
$this->db->join('store_category','stores.store_category_id=store_category.id');

$where="`store_title` LIKE  '%".$keyword."%'";
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->where('store_status', 1);
$this->db->where('store_type', 2);
$this->db->where('store_category.status', 1);
$this->db->order_by('store_title','ASC');
$this->db->order_by('store_category_id');
```

Comment: update the question to include the code that creates the query

Comment: I have updated my query

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would add an extra space after `and`, unless your `db` class does it. Is that a class of your own or a 3rd-party library?

Comment: No its simple search that add one more space after and keyword. And I am really shocked

Comment: Show the code for `$this->db->where()`, because that's what seems to be doing it.

Comment: @Barmar I have mentioned $where="`store_title` LIKE  '%".$keyword."%'"; and o/p is WHERE title LIKE  '%Bootjack Fire and  Rescue Foundation%'

Comment: Please show how you're getting that output in the question. Comments don't have enough formatting to understand what you're saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117694/discussion-between-amit-sharma-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert **multiple space into a single one** then use the same `like` clause.

```
$where="replace(replace(replace(store_title,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ') LIKE  '% replace(replace(replace(".$keyword".,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ') %'";
```

considering `<` and `>` symbol will not appear in that column value, otherwise need to use some other symbols.
**I have used this in SQL-SERVER should works in Mysql also.**

You can remove multiple spaces in `php` like below...

```
$keyword=preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$keyword);
```

then use the simple sql as...

```
$where="store_title LIKE '% ".$keyword" %'";
```

Comment: oops o/p is same  "WHERE replace(replace(replace(`store_title`,' ','<>'),'><',''),' <> ',' ') LIKE  '%Bootjack Fire and  re%' " as you can see double spaces after and word

Comment: The extra space is in the query, not the table data.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not possible directly in the query.

You can transform your keyword to repair any wrong data.

- Split the phrase -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php
- Trim all words to remove whitespace. -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
- Re-create the phrase correctly with one space.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I can do this but I want exact match and this is the first time that i have seen this issue that taking double spaces after and word

Comment: The keyword variable doesn't have wrong data. He's claiming that the space gets added when it gets put into the query.

Comment: Ok @Barmar, I did not understand the question correctly